# Split a JSON file into separate files

Tags: json, file, split, jq

I have a large JSON file that is an object of objects, which I would like to split into separate files name after object keys. Is it possible to achieve this using jq or any other off-the-shelf tools?

The original JSON is in the following format

`{ "item1": {...}, "item2": {...}, ...}`

Given this input I would like to produce files item1.json, item2.json etc.

Comment: Do you want to convert it to different files are different variables? There are so many ways, with which you can convert into different variables.

Comment: I want to convert each object represented by its own key to a separate file. Is there any way to do it with jq or similar tools?

Comment: You can only generate one output at a time. Just make up a script that would get all the item names, then fork out jq calls to get those items out and save to a file.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This should give you a start:

```
for f in `cat input.json | jq -r 'keys[]'` ; do
  cat input.json | jq ".$f" > $f.json
done
```

or when you insist on more bashy syntax like some seem to prefer:

```
for f in $(jq -r 'keys[]') ; do
  jq ".[\"$f\"]" < input.json > "$f.json"
done < input.json
```

Comment: To ensure proper behavior in the presence of any key name, it would be necessary to write ".[\"$f\"]" rather than ".$f"

Comment: `cat file | command` is anti-pattern, backticks is another one

Comment: `jq --arg f "$f" '.[$f]'` would be a further improvement, preventing arbitrary code injection (granted, not a big security issue until jq gets a `system()` call, or a way to open files for write, or other facilities that it doesn't currently have) by ensuring that the substituted value can only ever be treated as a literal string.

Comment: `jq -n --argjson f "$f" '$f'` will also guarantee a good parsing; `-n ` is important if your not piping

Answer (score 9):

Here's a solution that requires only one call to jq:

```
jq -cr 'keys[] as $k | "\($k)\n\(.[$k])"' input.json |
  while read -r key ; do
    read -r item
    printf "%s\n" "$item" > "/tmp/$key.json"
  done
```

It might be faster to pipe the output of the jq command to awk, e.g.:

```
jq -cr 'keys[] as $k | "\($k)\t\(.[$k])"' input.json |
  awk -F\\t '{ print $2 > "/tmp/" $1 ".json" }'
```

Of course, these approaches will need to be modified if the key names contain characters that cannot be used in filenames.

Answer (score 1):

> *Is it possible to achieve this using jq **or any other off-the-shelf tools**?*

It is. [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel) can also do this very efficiently.

Let's assume *'input.json'* :

```
{
  "item1": {
    "a": 1
  },
  "item2": {
    "b": 2
  },
  "item3": {
    "c": 3
  }
}
```

**Inefficient Bash method:**

```
for f in $(xidel -s input.json -e '$json()'); do
  xidel -s input.json -e '$json("'$f'")' > $f.json
done
```

For every object key another instance of `xidel` is called to parse the object. Especially when you have a very large JSON this is pretty slow.

**Efficient `file:write()` method:**

```
xidel -s input.json -e '
  $json() ! file:write(
    .||".json",
    $json(.),
    {"method":"json"}
  )
'
```

One `xidel` call creates *'item{1,2,3}.json'*. Their content is a compact/minified object, like `{"a": 1}` for *'item1.json'*.

```
xidel -s input.json -e '
  for $x in $json() return
  file:write(
    concat($x,".json"),
    $json($x),
    {
      "method":"json",
      "indent":true()
    }
  )
'
```

One `xidel` call creates *'item{1,2,3}.json'*. Their content is a prettified object (because of `{"indent":true()}`), like...

```
{
  "a": 1
}
```

...for *'item1.json'*. Different query (for-loop), same result.

This method is multitudes faster!