# split json file into object per file

Tags: json, python-3.x, awk, sed, jq

I have a JSON file, with a structure like this:

```
{
"106" : {
      "id54011" : [
         {
            "partno1" : "16690617"
         },
         {
            "partno2" : "5899180"
         }
      ],
      "parts" : [
         "0899180",
         "16920617"
      ],
      "id5632" : [
         {
            "partno1" : "090699180"
         }
      ]
   },
   "560" : {
      "id9452" : [
         {
            "partno2" : "1569855"
         }
      ],
      "parts" : [
         "03653624",
         "15899855"
      ],
      "id578" : [
         {
            "partno3" : "0366393624"
         },
         {
            "partno4" : "0363213624"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I need to split this JSON into multiple files, using this method:

Each JSON file will consist of one object. Using the example file above, I should end up with `000106.json`, and `000560.json`. (All names, must have 6 digits, so zeros must be added.)

I have tried to use an iteration grouper, in python, and jq, for this, but no luck up to now.

Expected output:
JSON file 1, named `000106.json`:

```
{
   "106" : {
       "id54011" : [
           {
               "partno1" : "16690617"
           },
           {
               "partno2" : "5899180"
           }
       ],
       "parts" : [
           "0899180",
           "16920617"
       ],
       "id5632" : [
           {
               "partno1" : "090699180"
           }
       ]
   }
}
```

JSON file 2, named `000560.json`:

```
{
    "560" : {
        "id9452" : [
            {
                "partno2" : "1569855"
            }
        ],
        "parts" : [
            "03653624",
            "15899855"
        ],
        "id578" : [
            {
                "partno3" : "0366393624"
            },
            {
                "partno4" : "0363213624"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON with Unix tools](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1955505/1255289)

Answer (score 0):

Since this question has both jq and awk tags, I'd recoomend using jq and awk as explained here: [Split a JSON file into separate files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28744361/split-a-json-file-into-separate-file)

You can easily pad the key names in jq or awk.