# Export each document of a mongodb collection into seperate json file

Tags: mongodb, export

I have a mongoddb DB called 'CRM' and in that there is a collection "users".

There are 50,000+ users into "users" collection.

I want to export all users documents from "users" collection to separate .json file.

I ran following command which gives me all users into a single (users.json)json file as an array of json objects.

```
mongoexport -d CRM -c users -o users.json --jsonArray
```

But, I want .JSON file for each users.

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: There is no way with MongoDB to do that. You probably should write a script that reads every document from your array and create a file. It s not really complicated ;-)

Comment: Is it possible to load 50000+ documents into an array and then one by one write data into file?

Comment: Yes it is. mongoexport will do the export of your 50K documents, then your script will read your file.
But my opinion is that you have better to do a script reading the collections and creating a file for each document... you could scale it, it would be more performant

Comment: Thanks. I will try it and post the status.

Answer (score 1):

[jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) helped me get this done.

The output file from Mongo is not a valid JSON file, rather individual lines of respectively valid JSON content. The steps I used were:

- iterated through each line,
- parse it to get the ID (you can use your own field here)
- use the ID as the file name
- write the line/document to a file

Here's the bash code I ultimately used:

```sh
# Make newlines the only separator.
IFS=$'\n'
# Disable globbing.
set -f          

# Iterate through the export file
for doc in $(cat < export.txt); do
  # $doc is a valid JSON document. Parse it to get the filename
  # based on the ID.
  export filename=`echo $doc | jq -r '._id'`.json

  # Write document to file.
  echo "Writing $filename"
  echo $doc > $filename
done
```

I learnt this from these Stack Exchange answers:

- [How to loop over the lines of a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/7012/39174)
- [Split a JSON file into separate files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28753393/434961)

I'm just not sure how well this will work for 50, 000 records.